# Can't make calculator app in Swift get more than one digit?

Tags: swift, append, calculator

So this is the class for my Operation:

```
class Calculation {

var currentNumber: String = ""
var resultNumber = Int()
var operationInput = String()


func operationIdentifier() {

    if operationInput == "=" {
        resultNumber = Int(currentNumber)!
        print("\(resultNumber)")
    } else if operationInput == "+" {
        resultNumber += Int(currentNumber)!
        print("\(resultNumber)")
    } else if operationInput == "-" {
        resultNumber -= Int(currentNumber)!
        print("\(resultNumber)")
    } else if operationInput == "*" {
        resultNumber *= Int(currentNumber)!
        print("\(resultNumber)")
    } else if operationInput == "/" {
        resultNumber /= Int(currentNumber)!
        print("\(resultNumber)")
    } else {
        print("Operation does not exist.")
    }

    print("\(resultNumber)")
}
```

And this is where I get this button to get the title for numbers:

```
@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    calculation.currentNumber = (sender.titleLabel?.text!)!
    calculation.currentNumber.append(<#T##other: String##String#>)
    //calculation.currentNumber.append((sender.titleLabel?.text)!) This is how I use it to append.
    calculation.operationIdentifier()
    resultTextField.text = "\(calculation.currentNumber)"

}
```

The append command is for strings as showed in the code section which I use to add to the end of the previous number, and the result is always a double of some Int e.g : If you press 5, it returns 55.

Comment: Please, add what do you want to achieve. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: @Luzo I'm writing a calculator, and I'm stuck with the part that I need to receive numbers from the buttons' titles. Problem is, it only gets one digit numbers. If you press the button to e.g 23, it returns 2 and then 3, as 2 is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are overwriting value here: `calculation.currentNumber = (sender.titleLabel?.text!)!`. Second, you will need to clear a current number after pressing.

Here is my concept for you(your edited code), you can try it in Playground.

```
enum Operator: String {
    case plus = "+"
    case minus = "-"
    case multiply = "*"
    case divide = "/"
    case equal = "="

}

class Calculation {

    var currentNumber: String = ""
    var resultNumber = Int()
    var operationInput = String()

    func recalculate() {
        if resultNumber == 0 {
            resultNumber = Int(currentNumber) ?? 0
            return
        }

        guard let sign = Operator(rawValue: operationInput), let number = Int(currentNumber) else { return }

        switch sign {
            case .plus: resultNumber += number
            case .minus: resultNumber -= number
            case .divide: resultNumber /= number
            case .multiply: resultNumber *= number
            case .equal: resultNumber = number
        }
    }

    func operatorPressed(_ op: Operator) {
        recalculate()
        operationInput = op.rawValue
        currentNumber = ""

        print(resultNumber)
    }

    func numberPressed(_ number: String) {
        currentNumber.append(number)
    }
}

let c = Calculation()
c.numberPressed("5")
c.numberPressed("5")
c.operatorPressed(.plus)
c.numberPressed("5")
c.operatorPressed(.multiply)
c.numberPressed("5")
c.operatorPressed(.equal)
c.operatorPressed(.plus)
c.numberPressed("5")
c.operatorPressed(.equal)
```

Comment: Thank you, but would you please explain the final part for me please? What is the concept of “c.numberPressed(“5”)” ? Is it for testing only?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It was done in playground so you adjust it for your code. Maybe you will find some weak spots. In general try to avoid !, name your functions properly, use enums to increase readability.

Comment: It works properly in PG but I'm still getting the same result as before, same as my own code.

Comment: So your problem is that if you tap button, the number pressed method is called twice? Because originally you said that you can’t write more than one digit to your number. So please adjust your question so we understand.

Comment: I have figured it out some other way using only append to a string array. But still don’t know why would these commands attempt to overwrite the number.

Answer (score 0):

In `numberPressed` you are setting `currentNumber` in from the label text and then appending the same value to it again. It should be something like:

```
@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let label = sender.titleLabel, let numberString = label.text else{
        return
    }

    calculation.currentNumber.append(numberString)

    print("currentNumber = \(calculation.currentNumber)")

}
```

Also, why do you call `calculation.operationIdentifier()` in `numberPressed`? Wouldn't that go in an operatorPressed method?

Comment: Does this command clear the previous number after pressing the operator?  And yes, you’re right.

Comment: it would not clear it. You will need to do that at the end of the `operationIdentifier` method or like Luzo has suggested in the `operatorPressed` action

Comment: It is still giving me a double digit of every number I press in simulator.